# Patched conic approximation targeting retrograde LLO yields prograde orbit

Tags: trajectory, cislunar, trajectory-design, patched-conic

I'm playing around with optimization of a patched conic approximation for a transit from earth orbit to LLO, and when I take the resulting retrograde trajectory and plug it into an integrator, I get a prograde trajectory instead. I've been trying to troubleshoot it for several days, but I'm stumped.

The figure below shows each iteration of the optimization. The triangle's vertices are earth (blue circle), moon (small grey circle), and the interception of the trajectory with the lunar sphere of influence *at the time of intercept* (dashed line). The arc is the elliptical transit trajectory from perigee to apogee. The red vector indicates the velocity vector direction just inside the lunar SOI. As the optimization gets further along, the lines and arcs become less transparent — so the darkest lines indicate the final results.

[image: patched conic overview]

The routine is optimizing for delta-v. You can see that as the delta-v converges on the minimum, the phase angle relative to the moon gradually increases. It also seems obvious that this should produce a retrograde orbit, since the moon-relative velocity takes it clockwise around the moon.

[image: patched conic in lunar SOI]

However, the propagated trajectory is clearly prograde, and doesn't reach the target periselene radius of 1837 km.

[image: propagated trajectory]
[image: propagated trajectory with periselene radius]

According to the authors of this optimization strategy (cited below), the method should work for prograde and retrograde trajectories, and should produce reasonably accurate results. I've also verified that the assumed earth–moon radius for the patched conic approximation only changes by 600 km between intercept and periselene, so I'm not sure how to explain this discrepancy.

Moreover, if I optimize only for departure velocity and don't optimize delta-v, I get a retrograde orbit, as expected.

In the plot below, I show to red dots to indicate injection velocity-optimized trajectories (one prograde and one retrograde) and a blue dot to indicate a delta-v-optimized supposedly retrograde trajectory. The white band indicates where the spacecraft would hit the moon (or be below LLO), so all points above it describe retrograde orbits.

[image: one prograde orbit and two retrograde orbits]

I also considered that the elliptical transit appears to intersect the SOI twice in the very first figure; however, this seems to be an artifact, since the moon and its SOI are only plotted at the conic change.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Any suggestions as to what might be the cause and how to fix it?

**Reference**

1. Arthur Gagg Filho, L., & da Silva Fernandes, S. (2016). Optimal round trip lunar missions based on the patched-conic approximation. Computational and Applied Mathematics, 35(3), 753–787. https://doi.org/10.1007/s40314-015-0247-y available without paywall at [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279235014_Optimal_round_trip_lunar_missions_based_on_the_patched-conic_approximation).

Comment: Can you plot your optimized trajectory against the propagated trajectory?

Comment: @RussellBorogove Ah! Yes. My plot was wrong in the same way my optimization code was. Had to do with the moon-relative flight path angle at arrival. Thanks so much!